# How to convert straight forward a dataframe column into a dataframe with column values as column indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the title is not good descriptive enought. I was not able to figure out a better description.
I hope the example will help to explain my question.
I have one dataframe with one column:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,2,3,3,1],index=(('blue','A'), ('blue','B'),('red','A'), ('red','B'),('black','A'), ('black','B')))

         0
blue  A  1
      B  2
red   A  2
      B  3
black A  3
      B  1
```

I want to transform the column into a dataframe with column indexes the values of the original column. This might be the result:

```
    Out[14]: 
         1  2  3
blue  A  1  0  0
      B  0  2  0
red   A  0  2  0
      B  0  0  3
black A  0  0  3
      B  1  0  0
```

It might be also good for me to get True/False values. Whichever is the more straight forward method.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
result = pd.get_dummies(df[0])
```

and you will get:

```
         1  2  3
blue  A  1  0  0
      B  0  1  0
red   A  0  1  0
      B  0  0  1
black A  0  0  1
      B  1  0  0
```

Values other than *1* are not needed, because the "true" source
value is in the column name.

If you want this result as a **boolean** DataFrame, append `.astype(bool)`
to the above code